# Chrome and CSS attribute selector

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I have the following HTML code, where I would like to format with css a data format (coming from xml) which can't be changed.

I have to give different styles to  elements with different attribute value. I thought to use the CSS attribute selector.

```
body {
    background-color: black
}
s {
    text-decoration: none
}
f {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
f[type=h2] {
    color: green
}
f[type=p] {
    color: blue
}
f[type=speech] {
    color: yellow
}
f[type=other] {
    color: gray
}
```

```
<b>
  <s> 
    <f type="h2">Title</f>
    <f type="p">Paragraph</f>
    <f type="speech">Dialgoue</f>
    <f type="other" br="true">Other</f>
    <f type="p">Paragraph</f>
    <f type="p">Paragraph</f>
  </s>
</b>
```

In Firefox the page is rendered as I expect (`h2` in green, `p` in blue, `speech` in yelllow and other in gray). In chrome everything is green.

How can I obtain the Firefox result in Chrome?

Comment: Are you using a doctype?

Comment: Few realize that you can style XML using CSS or alternatively, XSLT.

Comment: @Zenith The OP is trying to style an XML document instead of regular HTML...

Comment: @MarcAudet Oops, that shows me for going straight to the code!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html

Comment: is there an implied `<?xml ... ?>` at the top of this doc?

Comment: See also [When to use custom html tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags) http://alistapart.com/article/customdtds2

Comment: riccardo.tasso, you need to tell us whether you're trying to style an XML document, or you're trying to style XML embedded within HTML, or you're trying to style what you think are custom HTML tags. Otherwise the question seems confusing, and the edits by others aren't making it any better.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm using the cloud9 IDE to edit collaboratively the XML yoou see. I saw that such IDE has a "preview" button, and I was trying to use CSS to display my data. CSS on XML solved my problem. I didn't know about them (and Cloud9 IDE supports them in preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, Chrome is rather strict on HTML tags thus the CSS rule won't work well in the said browser.

A suggestion though, why don't you [style the XML](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html) instead?

Comment: Others suggested this solution. This is the simplest and clearest one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Changing attr name will help you , andi have no idea why

```
        <f custom="p">Paragraph</f>
        <f custom="speech">Dialgoue</f>
        <f custom="other" br="true">Other</f>
        <f custom="p">Paragraph</f>
        <f custom="p">Paragraph</f>


   <style type="text/css">
        f[custom=h2] {
            color: green;
        }
        f[custom=p] {
            color: blue;
        }
        f[custom=speech] {
            color: yellow;
        }
        f[custom=other] {
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: It's a kind of magic! Unfortunately it's impossible to me the change of the attribute name.

Comment: you can use jQuery to provide css for these elements with .css()

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is not valid. If you run it through a validator it spits out errors because it doesn't like the named embedded XML tags.

According to the [HTML/XML Task Force Report](http://www.w3.org/2010/html-xml/snapshot/#uc04):

> When an HTML5 parser encounters unfamiliar markup, it assumes that such markup is an erroneous attempt to generate well-defined HTML5. Consequently, it applies error correction strategies which result in a DOM representation that can differ radically from the DOM that an XML parser would have produced. In particular, open elements may end prematurely and additional elements may be opened.
>
> The practical result is that a “naked” XML island in an HTML5 document will not reliably produce anything that resembles the DOM one would expect from casual inspection of the XML island.

So Chrome is well within its rights to screw up here, 'cause technically you did it first. Of note is how (in my Chrome browser) [all the elements are green](http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/) (http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/) - which suggests that for some reason that all thing they're nested in a big `<f type="h2">` element. That is of note because HTML does contains a `<b>` and `<s>` tag, so `<f>` is the first invalid one it encounters.

[If we change the styles for that `f\[type=h2\]` rule](http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/1/) ([http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/)) it affects everything - which is consistent with the idea that somehow Chrome is interpreting this XML structure incorrectly. To Chrome's CSS engine (despite what the developer tools is telling us) this somehow looks like this:

```
    <b>
      <s> 
        <f type="h2">Title&lt;/f&gt;
        &lt;f type="p"&gt;Paragraph&lt;/f&gt;
        &lt;f type="speech"&gt;Dialgoue&lt;/f&gt;
        &lt;f type="other" br="true"&gt;Other&lt;/f&gt;
        &lt;f type="p"&gt;Paragraph&lt;/f&gt;
        &lt;f type="p"&gt;Paragraph</f>
      </s>
    </b>
```

Comment: Actually my interpretation of the resulting DOM structure might not be quite right ([http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/qJMWg/2/)) but the core message is the same: this is invalid HTML and Chrome can do whatever it wants with it.