# How to correctly write a CSS Attribute selector to extract all id attributes?

Tags: html, css, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

**Situation:**

I am currently attempting to reproduce, in VBA, the Attribute selector with syntax `[attr]` from  the CSS selectors exercises given [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp).

The selector is intended to select elements based on the value of the given attribute.

**Expected result:**

In the html sample I include, the expected result of trying to get **ALL** `id` attributes, using  `html.querySelectorAll("[id]")`, is highlighted in yellow when you run it.

**Problem:**

Instead of getting just the information associated wih `id` elements - the yellow highlighted bits - I am getting way more text. Looks like pretty much everything with some repeated material.

**What I have tried:**

1. I have read through plenty of CSS resources on this. They all state the same syntax. <sup>*See sample references</sup> . I haven't found a nicely matched VBA example so I may not be converting the syntax correctly.
2. In line with the above, ***only as a test***,  I tried altering the selector syntax to target a specific `id`. That worked perfectly.

For example:

```
 Set a = html.querySelectorAll("[id=""my-Address""]")
```

This, in my code sample, yields the expected value of:

```
<p id="my-Address">I live in Duckburg</p>
```

3. I tried removing the `[]` from `[id]` which printed nothing to the immediate window.
4. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090431/chrome-and-css-attribute-selector) has an answer that mentions Chrome ,the browser I am using, as being problematic with some CSS selectors but I don't think this applies to my scenario.

**Question:**

How do I correctly write a CSS selector, in VBA, to extract all the elements with id attribute from the given [webpage](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp)?

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

'[attribute] [target]  Selects all elements with a target attribute e.g. [id]

Public Sub Test13()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long
    Set html = GetTestHTML()
    Dim a As Object
    'Set a = html.querySelectorAll("[id=""my-Address""]")
    Set a = html.querySelectorAll("[id]")

    For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
        Debug.Print a(i).innerText
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetTestHTML(Optional ByVal url As String = "https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp") As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    With http                                    'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp60")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Set GetTestHTML = html
    End With
End Function
```

**HMTL expected result in yellow:**

```html
<div class="noSel">
<h1><span class="markup">&lt;h1&gt;</span>Welcome to My Homepage<span class="markup">&lt;/h1&gt;</span></h1>

<div id="helpIntro">
<span class="markup">&lt;div class="intro"&gt;</span>
<div class="intro">
<p style="margin-top:4px;"><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>My name is Donald <span id="Lastname" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);"><span class="markup">&lt;span id="Lastname"&gt;</span>Duck.<span class="markup">&lt;/span&gt;</span></span><span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
<p id="my-Address" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);"><span class="markup">&lt;p id="my-Address"&gt;</span>I live in Duckburg<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom:4px;"><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>I have many friends:<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
</div>
<span class="markup">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</div>

<br>
<div class="helpUl" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);">
<span class="markup">&lt;ul id="Listfriends&gt;</span>
<ul id="Listfriends" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">

<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Goofy<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Mickey<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Daisy<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Pluto<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
</ul>       
<span class="markup">&lt;/ul&gt;</span>
</div>

<ul style="display:none;"></ul>
<p><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>All my friends are great!<span class="markup">&lt;br&gt;</span><br>But I really like Daisy!!<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>

<p lang="it" title="Hello beautiful"><span class="markup">&lt;p lang="it" title="Hello beautiful"&gt;</span>Ciao bella<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>


<h3><span class="markup">&lt;h3&gt;</span>We are all animals!<span class="markup">&lt;/h3&gt;</span></h3>

<p><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span><span><b><span class="markup">&lt;b&gt;</span>My latest discoveries have led me to believe that we are all animals:<span class="markup">&lt;/b&gt;</span></b></span><span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>

<div class="helpTable" style="width:220px;">
<span class="markup">&lt;table&gt;</span>
<ul style="display:none;"></ul>
  <div class="noSel" style="margin-top:10px;">
```

**References:**

1. Mozilla: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. w3schools [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
3. [VBA/DOM - Get elements based on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282180/vba-dom-get-elements-based-on-attribute?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
4. [Unable to get CSS Attribute selector to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270345/unable-to-get-css-attribute-selector-to-work)
5. [Chrome and CSS attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090431/chrome-and-css-attribute-selector)

**Project references:**

<sup>*via VBE > Tools > References</sup>

[image: Project references]

Comment: what about this `"[id='my-Address']"` or simply this ``"[id=my-Address]"``

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. I want all the ids not just a specific one.  That was just to show I can select a single targeted id. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out two errors needed to be corrected.

1. The source website HTML was missing the closing `"` in the section `<ul id="Listfriends>` . This should have been `<ul id="Listfriends">`. This meant the CSS selector carried on matching.
2. I brought all the HTML from the page and queried that when in fact I wanted just the HTML within a specific `iframe` in order to work with only the expected ids.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long
    Set html = GetTestHTML()
    Dim a As Object
    html.body.innerHTML = html.querySelector("#iframeResult").document.getElementById("selectorResult").innerHTML
    Set a = html.querySelectorAll("[id]")

    For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
        Debug.Print a(i).innerText
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function GetTestHTML(Optional ByVal url As String = "https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp") As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    With http                                    'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp60")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = Replace(.responseText, """Listfriends", """Listfriends""")
        Set GetTestHTML = html
    End With
End Function
```