# Why does CSS selector of [id] bring match more text than expected?

Tags: html, css

**Situation:**

I am using the CSS selector of `[id]` i.e. All elements with an `id` attribute on the HTML shown below. I am getting back more text than I expected and I don't know why.

**Can anyone explain why I am getting more text at match element index 2 than I expected, based on what is shown in yellow when snippet run?**

The index 2 I thought would be simply everything relating to the `ul` tag

```
<ul id="Listfriends>
<li>Goofy</li>
<li>Mickey</li>
<li>Daisy</li>
<li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Expected results:**

I was expecting, from my research, the following results for the HTML shown, where expected matched elements are highlighted in yellow (when snippet is run):

```html
<div class="noSel">
<h1><span class="markup">&lt;h1&gt;</span>Welcome to My Homepage<span class="markup">&lt;/h1&gt;</span></h1>

<div id="helpIntro">
<span class="markup">&lt;div class="intro"&gt;</span>
<div class="intro">
<p style="margin-top:4px;"><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>My name is Donald <span id="Lastname" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);"><span class="markup">&lt;span id="Lastname"&gt;</span>Duck.<span class="markup">&lt;/span&gt;</span></span><span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
<p id="my-Address" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);"><span class="markup">&lt;p id="my-Address"&gt;</span>I live in Duckburg<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
<p style="margin-bottom:4px;"><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>I have many friends:<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>
</div>
<span class="markup">&lt;/div&gt;</span>
</div>

<br>
<div class="helpUl" style="border-color: rgb(255, 102, 102); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 153);">
<span class="markup">&lt;ul id="Listfriends&gt;</span>
<ul id="Listfriends" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">

<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Goofy<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Mickey<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Daisy<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
<li><span class="markup">&lt;li&gt;</span>Pluto<span class="markup">&lt;/li&gt;</span></li>
</ul>       
<span class="markup">&lt;/ul&gt;</span>
</div>

<ul style="display:none;"></ul>
<p><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span>All my friends are great!<span class="markup">&lt;br&gt;</span><br>But I really like Daisy!!<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>

<p lang="it" title="Hello beautiful"><span class="markup">&lt;p lang="it" title="Hello beautiful"&gt;</span>Ciao bella<span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>


<h3><span class="markup">&lt;h3&gt;</span>We are all animals!<span class="markup">&lt;/h3&gt;</span></h3>

<p><span class="markup">&lt;p&gt;</span><span><b><span class="markup">&lt;b&gt;</span>My latest discoveries have led me to believe that we are all animals:<span class="markup">&lt;/b&gt;</span></b></span><span class="markup">&lt;/p&gt;</span></p>

<div class="helpTable" style="width:220px;">
<span class="markup">&lt;table&gt;</span>
<ul style="display:none;"></ul>
  <div class="noSel" style="margin-top:10px;">
```

---

**Actual results:**

Instead I am getting:

[image: CSS query]

As you can see, I am getting additional text at index 2 i.e. everything after `ul id="Listfriends` as well.

---

**Research:**

I have read through many links including the following:

1. [Mozilla: CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. [w3schools CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
3. [Unable to get CSS Attribute selector to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270345/unable-to-get-css-attribute-selector-to-work)
4. [Chrome and CSS attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090431/chrome-and-css-attribute-selector)

They all state the same thing. I should use syntax `[id]` so I can only assume I am not understanding the HTML structure properly. But I am still confused why the query doesn't return the results expected as given in the learning demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp).

You can try the CSS query [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~pXSgyyjaCVNj3OWpcqqOl_jrEzU).

---

**Disclaimer:**

I asked this question before using a specific language [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061773/how-to-correctly-write-a-css-attribute-selector-to-extract-all-id-attributes). I can delete that question, if required, but I would rather try to understand now this problem from a CSS/HTML point of view, and then go back and see if there are any outstanding language specific implementation problems. I am really not sure on the SO etiquette in these circumstances.

I am new to CSS so please bear that in mind when responding. I am open to improving this question based on feedback.

Comment: Did you use the wizard to write this? :P

Comment: simply because you are missing the double quotes around the id Listfriends!

Comment: @ManojKumar LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you closing off the quotation mark in the id attribute for the ul field? In your screenshot it looks like you have:

```
<ul list id="Listfriends>
```

When you should have:

```
<ul list id="Listfriends">
```

I'm not sure if that's your actual issue but if the attribute isn't closed it may confuse a selector, since technically everything before the closing " will be included in the code.

Comment: I have copied the HTML exactly as is. The tutorial has no closing ". I will just edit it in to my query and see what happens. If that is the reason I might cry!

Comment: This is it ! The OP posted a link where you can try the query: http://try.jsoup.org/~pXSgyyjaCVNj3OWpcqqOl_jrEzU

Comment: Grrrrr....Damn tutorials. Thank you so much. I assumed it was me. I will accept when it lets me.

Comment: Don't worry, every single developer ever has spent countless frustrating hours of their career looking for a missing character ;)